# Views 3 - Add wildcard or "contains words" to contextual filters

Tags: 7, views

I setup a basic contextual filter in Views 3 and currently I have it pass in a field called "office" which is set by the $user. I have many different offices in my results with the string "new york" in it. Is there a way to return all results that has the string "new york" in it? Currently contextual filters only accepts an *EXACT match* string only.

[image]

Comment: `Currently contextual filters only accepts an EXACT match string only.` so like your office string has other stuff in it besides "new york"? such as `12345 Fake Street, New York` ?

Comment: yes some results are "brooklyn new york", "queens new york", "manhattan new york".... etc... thats why i need to be able to match non-exact items using contextual filters.